# Rails ActiveRecord SQlite3 datatype mismatch error on change_column from string to text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I am trying to change the datatype of a column from string to id. But SQlite3 is giving me a hard time. This is the only line in my migration:

```
change_column :containers, :title, :text
```

When the migration is running I'm getting an error of datatype mismatch:

```
SQLite3::MismatchException: datatype mismatch: INSERT INTO "acontainers"
```

I am pretty sure this is because of ActiveRecord creating a temporary table that has a id field with datatype INT while the original table actually has a datatype VARCHAR as can be seen here:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "acontainers" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to get around this. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in the SQLite wrapper.
You can try to update to the latest version if you're not using the one

As a workaround you can do the migration in multiple steps:

1. Create a new column
2. Write to both columns
3. Backfill data from the old column to the new column
4. Move reads from the old column to the new column
5. Stop writing to the old column
6. Drop the old column

It is also a safer approach as `change_column` may cause downtimes and errors
You can read more about it in [this gem description](https://github.com/ankane/strong_migrations#dangerous-operations)

Comment: Updating to the latest Rails version solved the issue, thanks!